# optionally execute pattern in html form validation

Tags: regex, html, forms, validation

I am trying to validate input in html form

following is my input

```
    <input type="text" name="workphone" class="form-control" pattern="[0-9]+"
        placeholder="Enter your Work Phone" >
```

I want to match the pattern optionally. This field is not required field, so its okay if user
doesn't enter anything, BUT if user enters something it should match the pattern.

Searched everywhere but couldn't found anything related to that.

Thanks

Comment: `^[0-9]*$` matches any digit zero or more times.

Comment: already tried that. If I don't enter anything then this works fine but when I add something which doesn't match the input and then click on submit I get error and then I remove everything from that input and then click on submit the error keeps coming even though the input is empty. Seems some bug to me.

Comment: What would be your input string?

Comment: I want only numbers. I am saying if I enter say some alphabets then click on submit, then it gives error as expected and then I remove everything from that input box and it still gives error which is unexptected.

Comment: also, if I directly click on submit without entering anything, I don't get error.